# remount file system with "adb remount" in production builds Marshmallow 6.0

Tags: applications, adb, 6.0-marshmallow, root-access

Before Marshmallow the solution of adbd insecure from Chainfire was working great on rooted Lollipop and previous builds.

But now, with Android 6.0 the adbd insecure apk doesn't work.

**Question:** is there another similar solution to adbd insecure, rather than mounting the file system with :

```
mount -o rw,remount /your_path
```

Regards

Answer (score -1):

Why would you want to do this?
Anyway,

```
adb root
adb remount
```

This should work. Works for me on my OnePlus 2.

Comment: Which kernel are you using? By convention OEMs do not allow adb to run with root privileges in production builds (stock kernel).